# Need advice to make a quiz in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to make a quiz application for iPhone. There are 10 questions in a quiz, has back question button ( go to previous question) and next question (go to next question).
User must be completed in 15 mins.

I am using UITableView to store answer (A, B, C, D) and user will answer by using "checkmark"
However, I meet some problem:

In question 1, I selected row 1 (B answer) is my answer. When I press next question, row 1 is selected, it's similar with other question when I press next question or back question button although I only answer question 1?

In your opinion, should I use UITableView or other object? If I use UITableView, Can I fix it?
Can you give me some recommend?

Thanks you,

Can you see my project: http://i5.upanh.com/2013/0826/06//57290900.screenshot20130826at11713pm.png

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ofcourse you can do it with `UITableView`. What I would suggest is to create a `NSMutableDictionary` like below, return the `questions` array count in `numberOfRowsInSection` and parse the dictionary and show it in UITableView.

The `Selected` variable inside the `answers` array can be bound to your checkbox in cell.
Add a member variable for keeping the current `questionIndex` (which will be 0 initially) and increment/decrement this value in next/previous button and reload tableview to update based on this index.

```
    {
        "questions": [
        {
            "question": "What is X?",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "Option 1": "X is 1",
                    "Selected": false
                },
                {
                    "Option 2": "X is 2",
                    "Selected": false
                }
            ],
            "correct_answer": "Option 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this gives you some idea.